# How to tell my project sponsor that few of the requirements cannot be met

Tags: communication

My technical team proposed new features than the initial requirements. How do I communicate the same to my sponsor ensuring he is kept satisfied?

Comment: Your question is too broad without context. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What framework you are referring to and what is a "sponsor"? Why is is not possible to just meet with them and say "hey, I have those great new ideas my team came up with"?

Answer (score 1):

You communicate honestly.  It's obvious telling your sponsor and other stakeholders good news keeps them happy but you can get the same results with honest, early, and transparent communications when you report bad news.  Set up a meeting, inform your sponsor your findings in a factual, non-emotional way, explain your findings around causes, report various alternatives including the features offered up by your team, explain the plus and minuses of these alternatives to your sponsor's business, and ask for a decision.  Nothing is certain about projects except this: change.  If the first requirements are not working, change them and keep going.